# iOS - UIView subview has different size than super view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, constraints

I'm creating an `UIViewController` with a subview that has the same width as the super view and half the height of the super view.

Here is how it looks in the storyboard:

[image: Views]

These are the constraints I added vor the `View Punkte`:

[image: Constraints]

Plus I added the "Equal Height" constraint.

The constraints work correctly. The subview stays the same when I rotate the device.
But the problem are the frame sizes.

When I print the sizes of both views, that's what Xcode returns (The code is inside `ViewDidLoad`:

```
print(self.view.bounds) // returns --> (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
print(viewPunkte.bounds) // returns --> (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 300.0)
```

Why is this happening? The width of the `viewPunkte` is not correct!
What is the solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of constraints did u apply ? Where did you print the bounds  in viewDidAppear or in view did load ?

Comment: Can you show the constraints you have on the view?

Comment: You can try 2 things. 1) Use autoresizing in subview. 2) Use `leading` and `trailing` constraint instead `equal width`

Comment: instead of applying equal width and equal height constraints for your view, try giving the leading ,trailing constraints.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Use [viewPunkte layoutIfNeeded] and then print bounds of viewPunkte. It should print correct bounds.

Comment: dont print the frame/bound values in viewDidLoad. Print them in viewDidAppear .@Mike_NotGuilty

Comment: That worked!! With viewDidAppear!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are inspecting the frame of a view during `viewDidLoad` then you are probably doing so after the views have been initialized but before they have ever completed a layout pass. Your controller's view has not yet been added to the window and you should not assume that the frames of any of your views reflect what their final sizes will be.

Consider why you think you need to inspect view frames at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the size of view controller's view in storyboard is not equal to simulator.It's square in storyboard but iOS devices are not in square shape.

It seems that you run your project in an iPhone/iPhone simulator

therefore:

self.view.bounds = iPhone screen size(pt) = (375.0, 667.0)

and you set up the height and width constraint of your 'viewPunkte', which are equal to the constant 300 & 600.

thats why the size of viewPunkte is constantly equal to (600.0, 300.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //NSLog dimensions.
}
```

This should give you the correct dimensions since this event means  its view has just laid out its subviews.

This is fired after viewdidload and before viewDidAppear. Orientation change can also fire viewDidLayoutSubview.